# How to get the absolute path of a folder, link dragged and dropped by react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, electron, react-dropzone

I'm creating an app on electron.

I want to get the dropped reference of the folder before it processing recursively inside files. 
And also if I dragged a link on the react-dropzone component I want to get the link also.

Here is my code so far. And I can get the file reference. But I can't get the folder reference.

The thing is if I add a large folder the component list all the inside files. I don't need that. I just need only the absolute path of the folder.

Here is my component

```
<Dropzone
  onDrop={(acceptedFiles) => {

      console.log(acceptedFiles)
  }}>
    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
      <section>
        <div className="board"
          {...getRootProps({
            onClick: (event) => console.log(event),
          })}>
        </div>
      </section>
    )}
</Dropzone>
```